# Issue working with partial mocks in Laravel 9.x

Tags: php, laravel, mockito

Hey there laravel developers, i found a problem with the partials mocks, i need to test a method that use a internal method, this need to be mocked, and i tried to use several ways to get that method mocked, like the next ideas:

```
#1
$mockMyClass = Mockery::mock(
    $myClassInstance
)->makePartial();

#2
$mockMyClass = $this->partialMock();
#3
$mockMyClass = $this->createPartialMock();

// and then

$mockMyClass->shouldReceive('internalMethod')
    ->andReturn($responseInternalMethod);
```

and obviously using the way that is described on the docs [Laravel Mocking Objects](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mocking#mocking-objects)

```
use App\Service;
use Mockery\MockInterface;
 
$mock = $this->partialMock(Service::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
    $mock->shouldReceive('process')->once();
});
```

and no one of this ideas works, the $mockMyClass is always executing the real method and not the mocked method that should return $responseInternalMethod. Some one have this issue too? i need to confirm if is a problem with Laravel, Mockito or something external and no a local environment issue haha. I read you guys!

Technical details:
Laravel 9.x
PHP 8.1
PHPUnit 9.5
Mockery 1.5

Comment: What do you mean with "_it is not working_", how do you know? Share the code you are trying to test (are you doing `new Class` or using dependency injection or `resolve(class)` or `app(class)` when you want to get an instance of it)?

Comment: You're right. I edited my question to add more details. The real problem is that the method described in the documentation is not working, as the mocked method is not being executed by the mockMyClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well guys, i found a solution for this, but anyways, i'm interested on know if someone have this issue too

The way that i resolved this was:

```
public function testRealExternalMethod()
{
    // Create a mock of the dependency that will be used by the class
    $mockDependency = $this->createMock(Dependency::class);
    
    // in this case we need to use a partial mock because we have an internal method
    $mockMyClass = Mockery::mock(
        MyClass::class,
        [$mockDependency, $parameter1]
    )
        ->makePartial();

    $responseInternalMethod = ['needed data'];

    $mockMyClass->shouldReceive('internalMethod')
        ->andReturn($responseInternalMethod);

    $result = $mockMyClass->realExternalMethod($parameter2, $parameter3);
}
```

the solution for these cases is create directly a mock instance of my class with all the needed parameters for the constructor as dependencies or data. And then use the mocked class as the real class to continue the testing cycle.